# TFS Email Error

Tags: tfs

we are setting up TFS 2013 for our company we have a problem in email alerts and configuration

after configuring the smtp settings and when we try to send a test mail we get the below error.

TFS Email Error:

[image]

Comment: At a guess, it looks like some of the server URL's could be incorrectly configured.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your connection of TFS are all normal.

As DaveShaw mentioned, please double check the configure of SMTP server. More details of configuration from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms400808.aspx

Note: the format of SMTP server should be IP address: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are sending emails from a windows account e.g thisman@outlook.com or thiswoman@live.com. This solved our email issue in TFS on prem

Comment: Wish I could provide more technical detail, we were getting all sorts of errors and bad authentication warnings at stages too. Created a outlook email and all problems were solved. Give it a go?

Comment: @astro8891 I create a outlook.com email and it do not work,  I use local windows account with TFS,  Is that the real problem ?

Comment: Was it resolved? Facing similar problems while configuring Email Client in TFS server 2018